# How can I optimize this SQL query with nested SELECT's?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT src_big, created, modified, owner, aid, caption 
FROM photo 
WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid, modified FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() or uid2 = me())order by modified desc) 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

This runs pretty slow, and I'm sure because of the nested SELECT's etc. How can I make this perform quicker? How should it be rewritten to be better optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use joins instead of SubQuery it is faster:

```
SELECT photo.src_big, photo.created, photo.modified, photo.owner, photo.aid, 
photo.caption FROM photo 
inner join album on album.aid = photo.aid 
inner join  friend on album.owner = friend.uid2 
WHERE uid1=me() or uid2 = me()
order by modified desc,created DESC LIMIT 30
```

Note: you need to put the table names at the end

Comment: my only tables are album and friend correct? how should I put them at the end?

Answer (score 1):

We have several instances in our Facebook games where this sort of functionality is necessary and we had lots of problems with it.  In mySQL it seems that each row of the outer query will rerun the nested query, which will rerun the one nested in it, making it very slow.  We found that returning the results of the inner query to php, concatenating it and then running the next query with the compiled list was much fast. Not sure it there is a solution entirely inside of mySQL but this solution works quite well for us.

Another potential problem could be indexing, you will want to make sure that all of the columns you are searching by or ordering by are properly indexed.  Using mySQLs Explain function on your query will also help to find problems.

Answer (score 0):

you could make it a join

```
select (stuff) from photo join album
on photo.aid = album.aid join friend
on album.owner = friend.uid2 
where friend.uid1 = me() or friend.uid2 = me()
order by created desc limit 30
```

BUT be aware: since you are using stored functions this will never get into the query cache.

You can see what's happening with your query by prefacing it with 'desc' - this will show you how the optimizer is dealing with it.