# I have one hell of an SQL query I'd like to optimize. Let's talk about it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

So, here's a question that will probably have the SQL experts jumping all over me calling me lazy, but I'm stumped. Our online store crashed and burned this morning, and here is the suspect query. I've thought about this all day, and haven't come up with any genius optimizations. Can I get some help? Any crucial indexes? Ways to restructure this? I realize this is like asking what's on the other side of the wall and then giving you a telescope pointed the other direction, but figured it was worth a shot:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT filename FROM (SELECT DISTINCT y.value AS label, x.value AS filename 
                        FROM   `catalog_product_super_link` AS z 
                        INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS y 
                        ON z.product_id = y.entity_id 
                        INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS x 
                        ON z.product_id = x.entity_id 
                        WHERE  parent_id = (SELECT entity_id 
                                             FROM   `catalog_product_entity`
                                             WHERE  sku LIKE 'F11-ARC-7710%' 
                                             LIMIT  0, 1) 
                        AND y.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                                               FROM   `eav_attribute` 
                                               WHERE  attribute_code = 'image_label' 
                                               AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') LIMIT 0, 1) 
                        AND x.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                                               FROM   `eav_attribute` 
                                               WHERE  attribute_code = 'image' 
                                               AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))) AS images WHERE c.value LIKE CONCAT(label,'%') LIMIT 0, 1) AS image,
                        pricing_value, 
                        is_percent, 
                        value_index, 
                        c.value AS label,
                        d.sort_order AS sort_order
                        FROM   `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS a 
                        INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS b 
                        ON a.product_super_attribute_id = b.product_super_attribute_id 
                        INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS c 
                        ON value_index = c.option_id 
                        INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS d
                        ON c.option_id = d.option_id 
                        WHERE  a.product_super_attribute_id = (SELECT product_super_attribute_id 
                                                               FROM   `catalog_product_super_attribute` 
                                                               WHERE  product_id = 5928 
                                                               AND attribute_id = 143 LIMIT 0, 1) 

                        UNION ALL

                        SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT filename FROM (SELECT DISTINCT y.value AS label, x.value AS filename 
                                         FROM   `catalog_product_super_link` AS z 
                                         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS y 
                                         ON z.product_id = y.entity_id 
                                         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS x 
                                         ON z.product_id = x.entity_id 
                                         WHERE  parent_id = (SELECT entity_id 
                                                             FROM   `catalog_product_entity`
                                                             WHERE  sku LIKE 'F11-ARC-7710%' 
                                                             LIMIT  0, 1) 
                                         AND y.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                                                               FROM   `eav_attribute`
                                                               WHERE  attribute_code = 'image_label' 
                                                               AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') LIMIT 0, 1) 
                                         AND x.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                                                               FROM   `eav_attribute` 
                                                               WHERE  attribute_code = 'image' 
                                                               AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))) AS images
                                                               WHERE label LIKE CONCAT((SELECT value FROM `eav_attribute_option_value` WHERE option_id = c.value LIMIT 0, 1),'%') LIMIT 0, 1) AS image,
                                        0 AS pricing_value, 
                                        0 AS is_percent, 
                                        c.value AS value_index, 
                                        (SELECT value FROM `eav_attribute_option_value` WHERE  option_id = c.value LIMIT  0, 1) AS label,
                                        (SELECT sort_order FROM `eav_attribute_option` WHERE option_id = c.value LIMIT 0, 1) AS sort_order
                        FROM   `catalog_product_entity` AS a 
                        INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS b 
                        ON a.entity_id = b.product_id 
                        INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS c 
                        ON a.entity_id = c.entity_id 
                        INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS d 
                        ON a.entity_id = d.product_id 
                        WHERE  c.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                                                 FROM   `eav_attribute` 
                                                 WHERE  attribute_code = 'choose_size' 
                                                 AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') LIMIT 0, 1) 
                        AND a.entity_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
                                            FROM   `catalog_product_super_link` 
                                            WHERE  parent_id = (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE sku LIKE 'F11-ARC-7710%' LIMIT  0, 1)) 
                        AND (b.qty > 0 OR d.manage_stock = 0) 
                        AND (SELECT value 
                             FROM   `eav_attribute_option_value` 
                             WHERE  option_id = c.value 
                             LIMIT  0, 1) NOT IN (SELECT c.value 
                                                  FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS a
                                                  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS b ON a.product_super_attribute_id = b.product_super_attribute_id 
                                                  INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS c ON value_index = c.option_id 
                                                  WHERE  a.product_super_attribute_id = (SELECT product_super_attribute_id FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute`
                                                                                 WHERE product_id = 5928 
                                                                                         AND attribute_id = 143))
                        ORDER BY sort_order
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This query is too long and complex to spend the time understanding so it can be optimised. Can you give a (small!) sample of input data, table structure and required output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick response.

Can you do it in the equivilent of PLSQL? 
Can you eliminate those subqueries?

Do them first and store the results. 
Assuming that they return a single row.

Then, write a smaller query passing in the variables.

Comment: PLSQL is Oracle-specific.  The tag says MySQL.  But the stored proc idea is a good one.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. All those subqueries are necessary to make this particular query work all the way through our various dev / staging / live environments (we're on Magento and anyone who is on Magento will understand - the IDs change). But breaking them up will just turn this into 7 queries instead of one...

Comment: In this case I believe 7 queries will be faster than one nested one.   It should also ne possible to detect which environment your on and conditionally build the correct query.

Comment: Resolved by splitting queries and caching the results of the subqueries so they are only executed once.

Answer (score 6):

it will be pretty much impossible without some more info and even your test bed...

BUT in addition to running the explain plan and adding indexes as suggested by others - i see some things that probably can be pulled out of there to improve things:

for instance you have repeated subselects:  like this one:

```
(SELECT entity_id 
FROM   `catalog_product_entity`
WHERE  sku LIKE 'F11-ARC-7710%' 
LIMIT  0, 1)
```

consider pulling these out to the highest level of FROM clause, and then joining to get the results. ONCE not many times.  if you do this for the 3 or 4 variants, you should see improvement.

another thing that doesn't look quite right is DISTINCT nested very deeply in the subselects...  you probably don't need those and they probably add overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, my.

I have nothing to offer except indexes on every column in WHERE clauses and EXPLAIN PLAN to see if there are TABLE SCANs.

My rule of thumb is that seven JOINS or more will perform poorly.  I count more INNER JOIN clauses than that in yours.  I would have serious reservations about this query.  Is it possible to denormalize?  What about VIEW?  Could that help you here?  You know your schema and problem better than I do.

Answer (score 1):

This question I answered the other day might help you out a bit:

[How can I optimize this SQL query with nested SELECT's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636629/how-can-i-optimize-this-sql-query-with-nested-selects/8636681#8636681)

It's about making nested queries more efficient.  I would suspect that if you processed your nested selects separately then used the results to form a simpler query it would help.  Granted tour query is much more complex so there is likely much more to it, but hopefully it's a start.